# Connectx-6 LX scheduled sending only sending 25 packets

Tags: dpdk, mellanox

We are trying to use send scheduling on a Connectx-6 LX. If we set no timestamps on the packet buffers and manually send each packet at approximately the right time everything works. However if we set timestamps in the buffers then the first 25 packets are sent and the packets are received at the expected times but all subsequent calls to `rte_eth_tx_burst` return 0. If its relevant we are sending a single packet in each burst with timestamps 125 us apart.

We've tried setting the timestamps to low values and the packets are transmitted correctly and as expected the `tx_pp_timestamp_past_errors` value is incremented. We also set high values and this worked too with `tx_pp_timestamp_future_errors` incrementing.

Any ideas where to start debugging this? I couldn't see any API which would give an error code for `rte_eth_tx_burst` failing.

We're using DPDK 21.08 with the 5.4.3.1 Mellanox driver on Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like this was caused by not having enough TX descriptors, we were only specifying 64, increasing to 1024 fixes the problem.